# Convert ISO 8601 to NSDate with AM/PM

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

In my application i get date from the API in the ISO 8601 format such as **2017-12-03T17:19:48Z** .

I wrote code to convert it to NSDate however when i print the output it prints out  **2017-12-03 17:19:48 +0000**

I would like to print something like this : **2017-12-03 17:19:48 PM**, how best can i achieve this.

This is my code :

```
-(NSDate *)dateFromISO8601String:(NSString *)dateString{

 NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
 NSLog(@"%@", date);

 return date;
}
```

Comment: You are converting ISO8601 string to `NSDate` object correctly (though, we admittedly can't be confident without seeing how you configured your `formatter` referenced above). But, when you just `NSLog` it, you'll always see `NSDate` objects in `2017-12-03 17:19:48 +0000` format with timezone info. If you want to output that string in the UI in a particular user-friendly format, you need a second formatter for that, to build a new `NSString` from the `NSDate` you parsed. I'm surprised you want `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:dd a` format for this second formatter rather than more user friend format, though.

Comment: We'd generally not set `dateFormat` in this second formatter when presenting dates in UI, but rather set `dateStyle` and `timeStyle`...